# flask __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

this might be a noob question but i keep getting this error for no reason

__init __() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

```
class test1(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # <-- it's right there 
idNo = db.Column(db.Integer,unique=True)
Name = db.Column(db.String(255))
Type = db.Column(db.String(255))
Date = db.Column(db.String(255))
style = db.Column(db.String(255))
from = db.Column(db.String(255))
pCode = db.Column(db.String(25),unique=True)



def __init__(self,id,idNo,Name,Type,Date,style,from,pCode):
    self.id = id  # <-- it's right there 
    self.idNo= idNo
    self.Name = Name
    self.Type = Type
    self.Date = Date
    self.style = style
    self.from = history
    self.pCode = pCode

 jD = {idNo:"Integer_value",Name:"value",Type:"value",Date:"value",style:"value",from:"value",pCode:"value"}
for j in jD:

         x = test1(
         idNo=j["idNo"],
        Name=j["Name"],
        Type=j["Type"],
        Date=j["Date"],
        style=j["style"],
        from =j["from"],
        pCode=pCode)

        db.session.add(x)
```

i keep getting this error on Python >> `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`
am I suppose to mention the "**integer Auto Increment** "  while making a new class ?
or do i have to remove it from `class test1()` and `__init __()`  ?

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation and include the full traceback. That being said, the call `x = test1(idNo=j["idNo"], ...)` lacks the id argument that your `__init__` expects. A typo perhaps? Or are you unfamiliar with how Python functions work?

Comment: can you specify which model library use and what does it refer `db`?

Comment: sorry i was in a rush i am working over night on this and also thank you for fixing it for me

Comment: @mathema just a json object of some data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either pass value of id while creating test1 object or remove "id" param from init function, because init is expecting id while creating object.
Auto increment of "id" can be handle by database. So you don't need to set the value of "id" using code.